# Can get to use db - 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'

Tags: mongodb

I just trying to start using beanie to handle MongoDB instance where I have few databases including admin.

My problem is that I getting following error whenever I try to connect to any other db than admin.

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

My initial code to check connection looks like this.

```
async def example():
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://root:<password>@localhost:27017/db1")
    
    await init_beanie(database=client.db_name, document_models=[doc1])
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(example())
```

Would anyone know how to connect to db1 instead of admin?

I'm pretty sure that is not some Beanie issue.
I just can't login to db1 using the root user.
When I try to create users with roles for db1 it prompts me with following.

```
{"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Could not find roles: readAnyDatabase@db1, clusterAdmin@db1", "code": 31, "codeName": "RoleNotFound"}
```